# Adicionar parâmetros ao IDbCommand

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Usei o método abaixo para adicionar parâmetros usando a interface `IDbCommand`

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using EstudoDotNet.Comum.Dominio;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;


public List<Laboratorio> ListarLaboratorio(int IdCidade)
{
    #region Conexão
    DALManager objDalManager = new DALManager();
    string connectionString = objDalManager.StringConexao;
    string connString = objDalManager.StringConexao;
    #endregion

    #region Comando
    StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder();
    sbQuery.Append("SELECT IdLaboratorio, NmLaboratorio, IdCidade ");
    sbQuery.Append("FROM Laboratorio lab ");
    #endregion

    #region Filtros
    StringBuilder sbFiltro = new StringBuilder();

    if (IdCidade != null)
        sbFiltro.Append("lab.IdCidade = @IdCidade");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sbFiltro.ToString()))
        sbQuery.Append(" WHERE ").Append(sbFiltro.ToString());

    #endregion

    #region Oredencao
    sbQuery.Append(" ORDER BY NmLaboratorio ");
    #endregion


   #region Execução


    List<Laboratorio> lista = new List<Laboratorio>();

    try
    {
        using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sbQuery.ToString();
                if (IdCidade != null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCidade", IdCidade);

                }
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Laboratorio laboratorio = new Laboratorio();
                        laboratorio.IdLaboratorio = Convert.ToInt64(reader["IdLaboratorio"]);
                        laboratorio.NmLaboratorio = reader["NmLaboratorio"].ToString();
                            lista.Add(laboratorio);
                    }
                }
                return lista;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei referenciar `System.Dataq.IDataParameter`, mas não achei.

Opções disponíveis para `cmd.Parameters.`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alterar para `SqlCommand` funciona normalmente.

Como solucionar este erro?

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida. Pode dar mais detalhes ou explicar de outra forma?

Comment: @bigown Adicionei mais informações.

Comment: Coloque como estão suas diretivas `using` no começo do arquivo.

Comment: Estou achando que o problema está em outro lugar. Não dá para perceber porque esse erro está acontecendo. Os `namespaces` necessário estão aí. Não sei se você está alterando consistentemente. Alguma coisa me diz que seu código está pior agora que antes.

Comment: @bigown Iniciantes são capazes de cometer barbarismo indescritíveis e incompreensíveis. O pior é que com `SqlCommand` funciona. O método retorna um `List` para preencher um `DropDownList` de laboratórios de acordo com a cidade selecionada em outro `DropDownList`,

Comment: Você não pode fazer o que você está fazendo. Você está editando e cada hora a pergunta é diferente do que era. Não tem como alguém responder e a resposta estar certa assim. Pergunta uma coisa e mantenha a pergunta assim. Você pode adicionar informações que ajude responder aquilo mas não mudar completamente o que foi perguntado.

Comment: Para adicionar ao que o @bigown disse, se quiseres mudar a pergunta, o melhor e' abrir mesmo uma pergunta nova, deixar a actual intacta e aceitar uma das respostas

Comment: @bigown Desculpe-me não tenho a intenção de atrapalhar ou comprometer a qualidade do fórum. E mesmo com as edições o escopo da pergunta permaneceu o mesmo. Só adicionei mais informações para facilitar a ajuda, tanto que o **dcastro** respondeu com a solução. Espero que este incidente não ocorra novamente, se porventura acontecer algo semelhante já sei que o caminho é criar um novo post. Mais uma vez me desculpe.

Comment: Não, a pergunta é completamente diferente da versão original, ainda que o assunto seja o mesmo. Aqui não é um fórum mas mesmo em um fórum se você edita a pergunta, inviabiliza. A diferença é que um fórum você pode naquele tópico complementando novas perguntas. Aqui não temos tópicos, temos perguntas, só. O dcastro respondeu a versão atual, não a versão original. O Cigano respondeu a versão original, a resposta dele está inválida para a versão atual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A propriedade `IDbCommand.Parameters` é do tipo [`IDataParameterCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.idataparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx). Este tipo não tem nenhum método chamado `AddWithValue`, apenas `Add` (definido pela interface `IList`).

Quando se usa a interface `IDbCommand`, os parametros devem ser criados através do método `IDbCommand.CreateParameter` e depois adicionados à colecção.

```
using (IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = sbQuery.ToString();
    if (IdCidade != null)
    {
        var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@IdCidade";
        param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        param.Value = IdCidade;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    }

    //...    
}
```

Comment: A pergunta mudou algumas vezes, então ficou complicado responder.

Comment: @bigown Eu nao vi o estado anterior da pergunta... mas no seu estado actual, é compreensível. O OP esta a tentar chamar o metodo `AddWithValue` na propriedade `IDbCommand.Parameters`

Comment: Sim, mas aí cada um vai responder uma coisa diferente, e nenhuma resposta será válida porque ele sempre muda a pergunta.. Esta pergunta está toda comprometida.

Comment: @dcastro Muito obrigado funcionou.